# Can't access my actual account. email address got reassigned to blank account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

Yesterday I posted a question on tex.stackexchange.com and I created a new user account:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/61504/sheik-yerbouti

I got the confirmation emails, clicked the links, set the passwords, etc.

Today when I log in using the same email address I keep being sent to a new blank account! (user61550, user61551...)

If I go back and click the links from yesterday's confirmation emails they also now send me to the blank new account. How do I get back to account 61504. I *know* the email address I used to register it but overnight it seems to have been reassigned to a new account.

Is there anything I can do? Can I log in using my userid instead of the email?

Answer (score 4):

The short version: I merged your profiles, so you should be all set.

The longer version: you originally posted with what we call an "unregistered" profile. Basically, the kind of profile that doesn't require signing up for and that you get when posting and just supplying your email/name at the bottom of the "Ask Question" page. From there, we encourage you to finish signing up and, ideally, just upgrade your profile to "registered". There is an occasional issue where that doesn't happen (it's on my list to fix), so I apologize for the confusion and the inconvenience.